# css specificty id vs attribute

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Having trouble understanding one particular specificity instance, maybe I'm over thinking it.

For example:

.class#id vs .class #id
In the first case, the html would be something like  right. So  to me this makes me think it's acting like an attribute. Does that change the specificity?

Edit: In other words I'm asking
.class#id : specificity=1-1-0
.class #id: specificity=1-1-0

Likewise, for instance
.class[id="id"] attribute or id?

Comment: Do you realize that `.class#id` means something completely different from `.class #id`? The first means an element with id=id and classname = class, the other targets a child with id=id and has a parent with classname=class.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case: `.class#id` matches

```
<div class="class" id="id"><div> <!-- matches this div -->
```

But this `.class #id` matches

```
<div class="class">
  <div id="id"> <!-- matches this div -->
</div>
```

Having no spaces in a CSS selector means they will apply to the same element. Spaces will imply child elements.

**Specificity**
In regards to your last case `.class[id=id]` is *almost* exactly the same as the first case: `.class#id` is "more specific" than `.class[id=id]` since `attr`'s in CSS have lower precedence than `id`'s.

For an excellent read on CSS specificity [look here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: Right but then what does that mean for the specificty? Are they the same?

Comment: @got2b Between `.class#id` and `.class[id="id"]`? Yes. Whichever is declared last will be preferred.

Comment: What about between .class#id and .class #id. I was leaning towards the same ...?

Comment: Those are different selectors, so specificity shouldn't be a concern. `.class #id` will style the `<div id="id">` inside a `<div class="class">`, whereas `.class#id` will only apply to the `<div class="class" id="id>` --> which is a different element.

Comment: Right, just trying to practice the numbering scheme with different examples. If I understand you right, they should all have the same specificity number, even though they are different selectors and will select different things (.class#id and .class[id="id"] being ultimately the same).

Comment: i think they are not same. check here https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/0atn7p8t/ Reference http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: Looks like you're right! I didn't know that `attr`'s had lower precedence than `id`'s.

Comment: aha this was what i was confused about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.class#id{ background-color:red} /*specificity 0110*/

.class[id="id"]{ background-color:green} /*specificity 0020*/
```

```html
<div class="class" id="id">lorem</div>
```

> for .class#id, Specificity is

- **0** for inline style,
- **1** for ID,
- **1** for classses,attributes and pseudo-classes,
- **0** for Elements and pseudo-elements

> for .class[id="id"], Specificity is

- **0** for inline style,
- **0** for ID,
- **2** for classses,attributes and pseudo-classes,
- **0** for Elements and pseudo-elements

Reference: [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)